# Get the values of particular columns and filter on a particular column - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script

```
function filter2() {
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //replace with source ID
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Users'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
var range = ss.getRange('A:G');      //assign the range you want to copy
var rawData = range.getValues()     // get value from spreadsheet 1
var data = []                       // Filtered Data will be stored in this array
for (var i = 0; i< rawData.length ; i++){
if(rawData[i][6] == "User missing")            // Check to see if Column E says No Billing Accountif not skip it
{
data.push(rawData[i])
}
}
var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('hsgsklllssdllsls'); //replace with destination ID
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Summary'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

}
```

This is a filter script. In this filter is getting value from source in the range A:G, but i need to get only Column B, Column D, Column F, Column G

How to avoid getting filtered Column A,C,E?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation:

One way to select particular columns is to use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

- The following will get columns `b,d,f,g` from the range `A:G`.

  `const rawData = ss.getRange("A:G").getValues().map(([,b,,d,,f,g]) => [b,d,f,g]);`

**Don't use a `for` loop to filter on a particular column.**

It is way more efficient to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter on a particular column. You haven't specified in your question for which column you want to filter on. Assuming the new data will consist of columns `b,d,f,g` the column indexes for the raw data will be `0,1,2,3`.

For example:

`const frawData=rawData.filter(row=>row[3]=="User missing");`

this will filter on column `g` since we have removed `a,c,e` and column `g` is in `3rd` position (starting from `0`). If you want to filter on a different column. Choose `0` for `b`, `1` for `d`, `2` for `f` and `3` for `g`.

### Solution:

```
function filter2() {
const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //replace with source ID
const ss = sss.getSheetByName('Users'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
const rawData = ss.getRange("A:G").getValues().map(([,b,,d,,f,g]) => [b,d,f,g]); // new code (gets b,d,f,g)
const frawData=rawData.filter(row=>row[3]=="User missing");// 3 means column G. [b,d,f,g] => [0,1,2,3]
const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('hsgsklllssdllsls'); //replace with destination ID
const ts = tss.getSheetByName('Summary'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, frawData.length, frawData[0].length).setValues(frawData);
}
```