# How to map specific column using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

From @soMario's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65394504/get-the-values-of-particular-columns-and-filter-on-a-particular-column-google) to a certain question, getting the data of specific column can be done like this:

The following will get columns b,d,f,g from the range A:G.

```
const rawData = ss.getRange("A:G").getValues().map(([,b,,d,,f,g]) => [b,d,f,g]);
```

How can I get the same, but using `getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),7)` instead?

Thank you!

Comment: `const rawData = ss.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),7).getValues().map(([,b,,d,,f,g]) => [b,d,f,g]);`

Comment: Hi, @TheWizEd! What I meant was how to avoid using column letters and use row and column references instead, in that case. Thanks.

Comment: In the map function [,b,,d,,f,,g] are not really column names they are variable names.  I could as easily used `map(([,,w,,x,,y,,z]) => [w,x,y,z])`.  And since map performs the function for each row its already implied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you getValues() of any range, it is stored as one array of many arrays, which looks like this, structurally for the range A1:G3 :

```
[ [ , , , , , , ], [ , , , , , , ], [ , , , , , , ] ]
```

when you want a specific "column", say column 4 of that range, in javascript/appscript it means you want the 4th element of each of the arrays in the array.  When counting from 0, the 4th element is the 3rd "index".

When using the mapping function, each of the elements of the array being mapped is assigned any variable you want.  It is common to use "e".  So for your specific case you would want to do this

```
const rawData = ss.getRange("A:G").map(e=>[ e[1], e[3], e[5], e[6] ]);
```

1,3,5 and 6 being the "indices" of columns B,D,F and G when starting to count with A as 0.

However, it's likely that you'll want a filter on your data as well to only return *rows* where there are values in column A.  If that guess is correct, you can apply a filter before your map like this:

```
const rawData = ss.getRange("A:G").filter(e=>e[0]).map(e=>[ e[1], e[3], e[5], e[6] ]);
```

Comment: Had forgotten to thank you for this one. Came back to refresh / fix knowledge. Thanks.